# modalSession has been exited prematurely - check for a reentrant call to endModalSession:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, modal-dialog, nswindow

I am developing a NSDocument based application. We are showing a window as modal window closing the window on a button action.(calling abortModal).This is working properly.

But when saved document opens it launches the application with opened document i am getting a this warning and making the window stale when user clicked on the button to close.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: The window isn't shown as a modal window so you can't close it with abortModal. Usually documents aren't modal. You can open multiple documents in multiple windows and switch between them. Don't use NSDocument based application for one modal document.